# IOS iPad application bottom strange white area

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I developed iPad tabbar application. I also use custom tabbar on left side. Bu Tab bar has white background along edges in landscape mode and also portrait mode. This area could not delete any of the method.

[image: iPad bottom]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the sizes you're using in your nib file don't match the layout in your app.  You'll need to set the autoresizing mask of your views so that they resize correctly at runtime.

You can change the autoresizing masks in the nib by opening the right-hand pane; selecting the icon that looks a bit like a ruler, and then clicking the red arrows.  Here's a picture:

[image]

The important arrows are the ones in the second row; click them so they look like this:

[image: Interface builder]

Your view should then resize correctly.